# Set timer on Java text

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a simple game app where user's are prompted a car brand and must then select the corresponding image. When the user makes a selection a message will appear indicating whether they are "Correct" or "Wrong". The issue I'm having is that the text will remain on screen until another answer is given, even though the images change.
How can I set a timer on the text so it clears as the images are refreshed?

Here's the code:

```
 image_clicker();

    image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (corr==0){
                result2.setText("Correct! Well Done!");
                result2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
            }
            else{
                result2.setText("That's Wrong, Try Again");
                result2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            }
             corr=image_clicker();
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a timer instead try "handler" it change what you intended to change with no delay, here are some documents about [Java Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) If you insist on using timer you can use Thread.sleep() instead. this delay the reading of the codes. [Thread Sleep Java](https://www.journaldev.com/1020/thread-sleep-java)

Comment: I'll check out the Java Handler stuff now, thanks for your help